# Pywinauto - How to read the text within a pop up window to identify it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, pywinauto

I'm trying to remote control a windows application that sometimes displays a warning window on startup using pywinauto.

The code below identifies the window because it has no menu.

I would like to read the pop up text to look for the phrase "Please contact your system administrator." within that pop up window to know that it's the
right one.

```
mywindows = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title_re=".*MyProgramTitle")

# proof that two windows are found
print(len(mywindows))

for handle in mywindows:
    print('\nhandle {}'.format(handle))

    app = Application().connect(handle=handle)
    navwin = app.window(handle=handle )

    if not navwin.menu_items():
        # no menu - I bet it's a pop up
        print('{} is the window I\'m looking for'.format(handle))
        navwin.print_control_identifiers()
```

The above code prints out all windows info, including 
    "Static - 'Location mapping failed. Please contact your system administrator.'"

But I'd need to catch that printout to further process it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a hacky solution I went through the source code of
`print_control_identifiers()` and found this way to loop through the controls of the window

```
navwin.print_control_identifiers()

for x in navwin.descendants():
    print (x.window_text())
    print (x.class_name())
```

Answer (score 0):

`find_windows` is very low-level entry point for automation. Using WindowSpecification objects you can wait for opening desired dialog/control or just check if it exists (all with customized timeouts).

See more detailed explanation in the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#entry-points-for-automation).

You can use `exists()` or `visible()` methods (return boolean value) instead of `wait('exists')` or `wait('visible')` which can raise an exception if failed.

For your case it may look so:

```
static = app.DialogName.child_window(title_re='.*Please contact your system administrator.',
                                     class_name_re='Static')
if static.exists(timeout=20): # if it opens no later than 20 sec.
    app.DialogName.OK.click()
```

Comment: Thanks, I spent a lot of time reading the getting started guide. Your approach requires that I need to know **Dialogname**. Finding out that is currently a bit of a challenge. Will this approach work if there are multiple dialogs with the same title (of which only one has the desired text)? How will `app.DialogName.OK.click()` know that it needs to click on `static` and not on any other window of the same name?

Comment: For default `backend='win32'` you can use `app.windows()` to deal with all top level windows. Say `print [wnd.window_text() for wnd in app.windows()]`. That's how to know `DialogName`.

Comment: If there are multiple dialogs with the same name, it's possible to use `app.window(title='Dialog name', active_only=True)` instead of `app.DialogName` to disambiguate search criteria. Or even more detailed choice: `app.window(title='Dialog name', found_index=0)`.